# How to form a Method based syntax in Linq Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

Iam using Entity Framework in ASP.NET Web application i have formed an linq Query to fetch the list of offers for the Employee in the location  using Query Based syntax . The query is given below.

**Main Linq Query**

```
using (var emp = new EmployeeEntities())
            {
                return
                    (
                        from p in emp.Employees
                        join pl in emp.EmployeeLocations on p.Id equals pl.EmployeeId
                        join l in emp.OfferLocations on pl.Id equals l.EmployeeLocationId
                        join po in emp.EmployeeOffers on l.EmployeeOfferId equals po.Id
                        where p.Id == employeeId && po.ParentId == SpecialGroupId && po.Id == offerid
                        select po
                    ).ToList().AsReadOnly();
            }
```

I want to know how to form a Method based syntax by using

> Where

and

> Include

like the below example

**Example Linq Query**

```
 return emp.EmployeeLocations.Include("OfferLocations.EmployeeOffer.Category").Include("Employee").Where(pl => pl.Id == locationId).ToList<EmployeeLocation>();
```

Can any one help me to form the method based query.Thank you

Comment: you can `accept` the answer no ?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your query couldn't you just do,

```
using (var emp = new EmployeeEntities())
{
    return emp.Where(p => p.Id == employeeId)
        .SelectMany(p => p.EmployeeOffers)
        .Where(po => po.ParentId == SpecialGroupId && po.Id == offerid)
        .ToList()
        .AsReadOnly();
}
```

Comment: [link]Thank you [/link]

Answer (score 0):

I found the Answer thank for everyone who helped replying with answers

```
 using (var emp = new EmployeeEntities())
        {
          var newres = intreat.EmployeeOffers.Where(po => po.OfferLocations.Where(ol => ol.EmployeeLocation.EmployeeId == empId).Any()).Where(pof => pof.ParentId == parentid && pof.Id != empoffer).ToList<EmployeeOffer>();

        }
```